# Issue with Prototype in JS

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

For my class I needed to create a constructor, object, and prototype. Unfortunately I cannot get the prototype to work and was wondering if someone could help me understand how to make a prototype to correctly calculate the price of my pizza object. Before I had to add an object and prototype it was working fine, but to meet the assignment guidelines I was asked to go back and make a prototype, which is confusing me greatly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//business logic
function Pizza(size, sauce, cheese, meat1, meat2, veggie1, veggie2) {
this.size = size;
this.sauce = sauce;
this.cheese = cheese;
this.meat1 = meat1;
this.meat2 = meat2;
this.veggie1 = veggie1;
this.veggie2 = veggie2;
}
Pizza.prototype.pizzaPrice = function() {
return pizzaPrice = inputtedSize + inputtedSauce + inputtedCheese + inputtedMeatOne + inputtedMeattwo + inputtedVeggieOne + inputtedVeggieTwo + 0;
}

//user interface logic
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$("form").fadeOut();
var inputtedSize = parseInt($("#size").val());
var inputtedSauce = parseInt($("#sauce").val());
var inputtedCheese = parseInt($("#cheese").val());
var inputtedMeatOne = parseInt($("#meat1").val());
var inputtedMeattwo = parseInt($("#meat2").val());
var inputtedVeggieOne = parseInt($("#veggie1").val());
var inputtedVeggieTwo = parseInt($("#veggie2").val());
var sizeChoice = $( "#size option:selected" ).text();
var sauceChoice = $( "#sauce option:selected" ).text();
var cheeseChoice = $( "#cheese option:selected" ).text();
var meatChoiceOne = $( "#meat1 option:selected" ).text();
var meatChoiceTwo = $( "#meat2 option:selected" ).text();
var veggieChoiceOne = $( "#veggie1 option:selected" ).text();
var veggieChoiceTwo = $( "#veggie2 option:selected" ).text();
var pizza = Pizza();
var newPizza = (inputtedSize + inputtedSauce + inputtedCheese + inputtedMeatOne + inputtedMeattwo + inputtedVeggieOne + inputtedVeggieTwo);
Pizza.pizzaPrice(newPizza);
$("#total").fadeIn();
$(".total").text(" " + "$" + newPizza);
$(".size").text(" " + sizeChoice);
$(".sauce").text(" " + sauceChoice);
$(".cheese").text(" " + cheeseChoice);
$(".meat1").text(" " + meatChoiceOne);
$(".meat2").text(" " + meatChoiceTwo);
$(".veggie1").text(" " + veggieChoiceOne);
$(".veggie2").text(" " + veggieChoiceTwo);
 });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of things wrong with this code.  To start with, you create a new Pizza object with `new Pizza(...)`, not with `Pizza(...)`. Then, you're trying to use variables like `inputtedSize` from one scope that are declared in some other scope.  You can't do that. Then, you're not passing arguments to `new Pizza()`. I'd suggest you start by looking in the debug console at what errors are being reported and solve them one at a time until there are no more errors.  One thing all beginners should do is learn how to see what's in the debug console.

Comment: Maybe you're getting a "not enough indenting" exception.

Comment: The indenting is fine in the actual html, the spacing is off because I had to indent awkwardly on here for the code to show up properly

Comment: @AddisonNishijima There are hundreds of thousands of posts on SO with proper indentation with the code showing up just fine. Please re-read the guidelines for code formatting. Anyway, I'd suggest going back and re-reading some basic tutorials on writing constructors and prototype methods and instantiating objects and referring to their properties from within methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pizza = Pizza(); //undefined
var pizza = new Pizza() //your obj
```

i am new, but try this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.

Comment: That's good as far as it goes, but it by no means solves all the OP's problems.

Comment: This is only one of many things wrong with the OP's code.  It is not even close to sufficient to fix the OP's code and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're instantiating your object incorrectly. You must prefix new object instances with the self explanatory [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator.

Secondly, you reference instance values with [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). In an prototype function, you can access instance variables by prefixing the variable with `this`. Doing `this.size = size` in the constructor will yield the value you passed to the constructor anytime you call `this.size`. Therefore your functions should reference those values like so instead of the variable which you're setting the input val from.

Here's how your code should look:

```js
function Pizza(size, sauce, cheese, meat1, meat2, veggie1, veggie2) {
  this.size = size;
  this.sauce = sauce;
  this.cheese = cheese;
  this.meat1 = meat1;
  this.meat2 = meat2;
  this.veggie1 = veggie1;
  this.veggie2 = veggie2;
}
Pizza.prototype.price = function() {
  return this.size + 
    this.sauce + 
    this.cheese + 
    this.meat1 + 
    this.meat2 + 
    this.veggie1 + 
    this.veggie2 + 0;
}

var pizza = new Pizza(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1);

console.log(pizza) // Pizza instance
console.log(pizza.price()) // returns computed instance values
console.log(pizza.sauce) // access instance value
```

In your case, you would use the above example like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("form").fadeOut();
    var inputtedSize = parseInt($("#size").val());
    var inputtedSauce = parseInt($("#sauce").val());
    var inputtedCheese = parseInt($("#cheese").val());
    var inputtedMeatOne = parseInt($("#meat1").val());
    var inputtedMeattwo = parseInt($("#meat2").val());
    var inputtedVeggieOne = parseInt($("#veggie1").val());
    var inputtedVeggieTwo = parseInt($("#veggie2").val());
    var sizeChoice = $("#size option:selected").text();
    var sauceChoice = $("#sauce option:selected").text();
    var cheeseChoice = $("#cheese option:selected").text();
    var meatChoiceOne = $("#meat1 option:selected").text();
    var meatChoiceTwo = $("#meat2 option:selected").text();
    var veggieChoiceOne = $("#veggie1 option:selected").text();
    var veggieChoiceTwo = $("#veggie2 option:selected").text();

    var pizza = new Pizza(inputtedSize, inputtedSauce, inputtedCheese, inputtedMeatOne, inputtedMeattwo, inputtedVeggieOne, inputtedVeggieTwo);

    $("#total").fadeIn();
    $(".total").text(" " + "$" + pizza.price());
    $(".size").text(" " + pizza.size);
    $(".sauce").text(" " + pizza.sauce);
    $(".cheese").text(" " + pizza.cheese);
    $(".meat1").text(" " + pizza.meat1);
    $(".meat2").text(" " + pizza.meat2);
    $(".veggie1").text(" " + pizza.veggie1);
    $(".veggie2").text(" " + pizza.veggie1);
  });
});
```