# Objects & Prototypes

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype

[image: javascript/jQuery File]

This is the code I am working with. It works when newOrder is just set to:

```
var newOrder = (toppingsTotal + inputtedSize);
```

but whenever I try to call the prototype it says its undefined in the JS console.

I'm still fairly new to this kind of material.Keep that in mind.

What I'm trying to is add up toppings and size, and use the prototype/object combo in my output.

Any help is appreciated!

an Aspiring Coder.

Comment: Screenshots of code are useless

Comment: 1) Your `Pizza` constructor expects three arguments yet you are only passing one. 2) The method name is `pizzaPrice`, not `price`. 3) Your `Pizza` instance is `newOrder` so you would call `newOrder.pizzaPrice()`

Comment: This question looks an awful lot like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240070/issue-with-prototype-in-js#comment65817037_39240070.   Perhaps this is homework or two people working on the same problem?

Comment: Screenshots of code will be immediate downvotes as not nearly as useful as actual text of the code, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `PIZZA` function expect three`(topping,size,price`) parameters, but your passing single parameter so that remaining 2 parameters`(size, price)` are undefind.

```
function Pizza(topping, size, price) {
  this.topping=topping;
  this.size=size;
  this.price=price;
}
```

Pass three arguments for this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Pizza` constructor has three parameters:

```
function Pizza(topping, size, price) {
  // ...
}
```

...but you're only passing one argument:

```
new Pizza(toppingsTotal + inputtedSize);
```

Therefore the pizza's `this.topping` is going to be the sum of `toppingsTotal` and `inputtedSize`, and the rest will be `undefined`.

Make sure your arguments align with your parameters, or your `Pizza` will not behave as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Substitute `newOrder.price()` for `Pizza.pizzaPrice()` to reference the object `newOrder` at call to `Pizz.prototype.pizzaPrice()`.

Though, note, you have not passed `size` or `price` parameters to at `var newOrder = new Pizza(toppingsTotal + inputtedSize)`; and you are calling `.price()` where function name is `pizzaPrice`

At stacksnippets below, three parameters are passed to `new Pizza()` and `newOrder.pizzaPrice()` is used to call `Pizza.prototype.pizzaPrice`

```js
function Pizza(topping, size, price) {
  this.topping = topping;
  this.size = size;
  this.price = price;
}

Pizza.prototype.pizzaPrice = function() {
  return this.topping + this.size
}

var newOrder = new Pizza("cheese", 12, 10.00);

console.log(newOrder.pizzaPrice());
```

Comment: I tried that before and it says its not a function in the JS console.